# Textwatcher android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, append, textwatcher

I have a `TextWatcher` on my android app.
Problem is I want it to listen on every text change, and append a string of the same `TextView`.

For example, a user inputs `A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9` on the `EditText` field, then I want a textview right on top to hyphenate after 6 characters. so the text view dispalys
`A1A2A3-A4A5A6-A7A8A9`, while the edit text still diplays `A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9`

I tried this on aftertextchanged, and it did not work:

```
    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    String hyphenated = "";


    if (s.length() == 6)
    {
        hyphenated = s.toString()+"-";
        mCounter.setText(hyphenated);
    }

    if (s.length() == 12)
    {
        hyphenated = s.toString()+"-";
        mCounter.setText(hyphenated);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does this display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
    String myString = "A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9";
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(myString);
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(i == 6){
            str.insert(i, "-");
        }
        if(i == 13){
            str.insert(i, "-");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Output would be: `A1A2A3-A4A5A6-A7A8A9`

Comment: The only problem is that is this on every time the user inputs a character, or only after the focus is off?

Comment: I don't know how did you setup `TextWatcher` this is the solution for your problem and rest is on upon you and try with `onTextChanged`.

Comment: Thank you this worked for my question! However, I now have a dilemma where if someone pastes a string and it also has hyphens, then it still adds a second one after that. ` if((i == 6) && (str.charAt(str.length()-1 != '-')));` Trying something like that didn't work.

Comment: For `String` you can use `contains` method. Check that out